# matplotlib DEBUG Turn off when python DEBUG is on to debug rest of program

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I turn on DEBUG in the python logger, matplotlib prints 10,000 lines of debug code that I do not want to see. I tried:

```
plt.set_loglevel("info")
```

as in their documentation, but still doesn't turn it off.  I put the statement right after importing matplotlib, and tried it right after creating the plot with `fig=plt.figure(...)`.

Neither works. Help?
ubuntu20.04, python 3.8.5, matplotlib 3.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate logger for your messages so you log only what you require.

E.g. from [logging doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) and [Matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stackplot_demo.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('no_spam')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# add formatter to ch
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.info("Starting")

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
y2 = [0, 4, 2, 6, 8]
y3 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

y = np.vstack([y1, y2, y3])

labels = ["Fibonacci ", "Evens", "Odds"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(x, y1, y2, y3, labels=labels)
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
logger.debug("About to show plot")
plt.show()
logger.info("Finished")
```

This should generate console output like:

```
2021-01-15 17:33:17,431 - no_spam - INFO - Starting
2021-01-15 17:33:17,635 - no_spam - DEBUG - About to show plot
2021-01-15 17:33:21,491 - no_spam - INFO - Finished
```

Or, if you set the logging level to `INFO`:

```
2021-01-15 17:34:18,987 - no_spam - INFO - Starting
2021-01-15 17:34:22,212 - no_spam - INFO - Finished
```

Comment: Interesting...let me play with it, as I do not understand yet why the matplot debug bonanza doesn't print also. Thank you so much for taking the time. I'll get back in a few. 1 on the up !

Comment: When you call `plt.set_loglevel("info")` you're setting the log level for the _matplotlib_ logger, which is using the default logger. In this example, I create my own logger. If you're working on larger projects, it can make sense to use separate loggers for specific debugging.

Comment: So, I should set it to python logging levels: 
plt.set_loglevel("NOTSET")
to turn it off.

Thanks.

Comment: You needn't call `plt.set_loglevel(…)` at all unless you're interested in specific internals of the matplotlib module.

Answer (score 2):

I found this useful for disabling matplotlib loggers:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.set_loglevel (level = 'warning')
```

If you are saving your graphs as png files, you also have to disable the [PIL (PngImagePlugin)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) logger. PIL uses the [logging libary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) for this

To do this:

```py
# get the the logger with the name 'PIL'
pil_logger = logging.getLogger('PIL')  
# override the logger logging level to INFO
pil_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

you can also choose another logging level instead of `INFO`: [documentation about logging levels](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels)